# How to define package level files?

Tags: go

I have a template in package `notifications`

```
/notifications
/html/notify.tpl
```

The issue is that if I call the functions of this package from a different path/package it can't find the file anymore as the program is assuming the path belongs to the package that is calling.
e.g.

```
ls
 main.go
/notifications
/html/notify.template
```

go run main.go

```
open html/notify.tpl: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

You either provide a path through configuration, use a well-known fully qualified path, use a path relative to your working directory (not recommended), or a combination of the three.

Comment: I think it will break the tests when I switch the machine. I'm considering using ``filepath`` package + ``$GOPATH`` env variable though I didn't figure it out yet how to use it.

Comment: well, `$GOPATH/src + import/path` is a well known, fully qualified path. There's no reason you can't put some simple logic around it to work for tests and deployment.

Comment: for some reasons it doesn't seem to find the $GOPATH path ...says it doesn't exist. Any idea why ? The path is set and valid if I try  from the command line (`ls`) so I can only assume . `err = filepath.Walk("$GOPATH", changePath)` ..  `lstat $GOPATH: no such file or directory``

Comment: `filepath.Walk` isn't executing anything in a shell, and `$GOPATH` is an environment variable - use `os.Getenv("GOPATH")`.

Comment: Thansk! I ended up with os.ExpandEnv